# Oracle SQL returns error when selecting more than one field without an aggregate expression

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am working with SQL queries and I have a table with months and prices and I am performing a Moving Average. My code is as follows:

```
 SELECT month, prices,
 round(AVG(SUM(prices)) OVER
   (ORDER BY month ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),2)
    AS MA
    FROM tblma
    GROUP BY month
    ORDER BY month;
```

Although to me it seems right obviously I am making a mistake I don't see. 
My retuned error is: 00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

My original data has the following format:

ID |  MONTH |  PRICE

1  |   11   |   20.36

2  |   12   |   11.05

Basically I would like to add the Moving Average column at the right.

Comment: You can't chain the aggregates `avg` and `sum` together like that.  You'll need to use a subquery instead and reaggregate over it.  Sample data and desired results could be helpful.

Comment: You have `prices` in the select list - not aggregated and not in the group-by. It isn't quite clear what you want - are there multiple price entries per month, and if so what do you want to see for the current month, in addition to the moving average? I'd guss you meant `sum(prices)` but not sure. And what does any of this have to do with the question title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to select `prices` but without an aggregate expression, or grouping by the price. If you remove the `prices` and just do `SELECT month, round(AVG(SUM(prices))` something will be returned. The reason that you cannot select `prices` as well is if you have more than one price for the same month then you haven't specified how to deal with this.

Also, `round(AVG(SUM))` will just return the rounded `SUM` of the values. It will first sum everything up, and then take the average of that number, which will be the number itself.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably what you want, the Moving Average over the Summmed prices:

```
SELECT month, SUM(prices),
 round(AVG(SUM(prices)) OVER
   (ORDER BY month ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),2)
    AS MA
    FROM tblma
    GROUP BY month
    ORDER BY month;
```